# jQuery on click redirect to child href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to link one div with the href attribute of his first `<a>` href.
My html looks like this

```
<div class="clicked">
<a class="i-want-this-href" href="target">
    <img>
</a>
<a class="this-one-is-useless" href="Wrong-target">
    <img>
</a>
</div>
```

And I have tested some different ways like this:

```
$('.clicked').on('click',function(){
   aux= $('this:first-child').attr("href");
   console.log(aux);
});
```

But I always get `Undefined` on the console. And I want to get "target" inside the first `<a>` element.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect, you can use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)/[`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) along with [:first](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector

```
aux= $(this).find('a:first').attr("href");
```

Comment: Wow,! I have no words, you´re fast as hell and ur response is working. I will mark it as solution as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` context along with `:first-child` selector

```js
$('.clicked').on('click', function() {
  var href = $(this).find('a:first-child').attr("href");
  console.log(href);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clicked">
  <a class="i-want-this-href" href="target">
    <img>
  </a>
  <a class="this-one-is-useless" href="Wrong-target">
    <img>
  </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong selector, If you want to use this in selector you should pass it separared as follows :

```
var aux = $('a', this).prop("href");
//Or
var aux = $(this).find('a').prop("href");
```

**NOTE :** jQuery by default will select the first occurrence.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.clicked').on('click',function(){
   var aux = $('a', this).prop("href");
   console.log(aux);
});
```

```css
.clicked{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clicked">
  <a class="i-want-this-href" href="target">
    Image 1
  </a>
  <a class="this-one-is-useless" href="Wrong-target">
    Image 2
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Do not use `this` in selectors, this needs to be passed to `$` separately

2) Make sure to declare variable as local, otherwise there will be bugs.

3) Use `first-of-type`

```
$('.clicked').on('click',function(){
   var aux = $(this).find('a:first-of-type').attr("href");
   console.log(aux);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.clicked').on('click',function(){
   aux= $(this).find('a:first-child').attr("href");
   console.log(aux);
});
```